# I need to write an if statement in Excel based on 3 different cells condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-columns

What I need is If cell A1="B" AND B1>1 AND C1<70%, then it will be "Exceptional", otherwise, it will be note as "Normal". There are 3 requirements for it to be "Exceptional", I need put all into excel.

My Formula input in excel is show as per below

```
"=IF(AND(G2="B",C2>1,I2<70%),"Exceptional",IF(AND(G2="C",C2>1,F2<=65%),"Exceptional",IF(AND(G2="D",C2>1,F2<=50%),"Exceptional",IF(AND(G2="E",C2>1,F2<=50%),"Exceptional","Correct"))))"
```

However it only apply for Situation 1 but not remaining.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the nested if's in your code by putting the AND condition inside an OR like this.

```
=IF(AND(A1="B",B1>1,C1<0.7),"Exceptional","Normal")
```

Or if you testing G2 for B,C,D,E like in you code it should be like this.

```
=IF(OR(AND(G2="B",C2>1,I2<70%),AND(G2="C",C2>1,F2<=65%),AND(G2="D",C2>1,F2<=50%),AND(G2="E",C2>1,F2<=50%)),"Exceptional","Correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use this code:

```
=IF(AND(A1="B";B1>1;C1<70%);"Exceptional";"Normal")
```

I tested it out and it worked for me, normally it should also work for you

Comment: For testing the percentage in the expression you should have C1<70% or C1<0.7, your answer would return Exceptional if 6999% was in cell C1

Comment: @pchan-ie I noticed it while running other tests, but thank you anyway for finding that problem.

And i didn't know if it was 6999% it would also return that, I learned something new, thanks